# How can I monitor dev tunnel traffic in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, dev-tunnels

Visual Studio 2022 17.6 introduced support for dev tunnels [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/dev-tunnels?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Previously, developers would need to set up ngrok to forward external traffic to their local dev machines for testing. ngrok provides the capability to monitor traffic through the tunnel via its web inspection interface. Is there a way to similarly monitor traffic through Visual Studio's dev tunnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "-inspect" to the dev tunnel url to view the inspection interface. For dev tunnel `ID-8080.usw2.devtunnels.ms` the inspection interface is
`ID-8080-inspect.usw2.devtunnels.ms`

Thanks @derekbekoe via [X](https://twitter.com/derekbekoe/status/1700307559922692583)